# PhpStorm - cURL is not working

Tags: php, curl, phpstorm, php-extension, php-curl

I am using PhpStorm's built-in PHP server for testing my website. I need cURL support. In my php.ini I have uncommented `extension=php_curl.dll`, and I have installed cURL onto my computer (it works from the command line). I have also restarted PhpStorm, and still, it says that any of the curl functions (`curl_init`, `curl_version`, etc.) are undefined.

After some research I have ended up running `phpinfo()`. cURL is not shown on the list of extensions.

Under the interpreter configuration (Settings > Languages > PHP > CLI Interpreter > ...) I even clicked the "open php.ini in the editor" button, to make sure they were the same. When it opened php.ini in the editor (PhpStorm) the line was uncommented too, so PhpStorm is referencing the correct file.

Why isn't cURL working on PhpStorm?

Comment: How exactly did you run the `phpinfo()`? Do you have a local PHP installation set up in `Settings > Languages > PHP > CLI Interpreter > ...`? The point here is to make sure that the phpinfo() page was generated by an Interpreter that you have selected in IDE. If you have several PHP installations you might be getting the phpinfo of another local PHP webserver

Comment: The only interpreter I configured was a local one, the only PHP download I have

Answer (score 0):

> I have also restarted PhpStorm, and still, it says that any of the curl functions (curl_init, curl_version, etc.) are undefined.

PhpStorm should be able to recognize those functions despite the curl.dll availability in php.ini file. Could you please attach a screenshot illustrating the issue in IDE?

> I have ended up running phpinfo(). cURL is not shown on the list of extensions.

Did you restart Web Server after uncommenting the line in php.ini?

Could you please also share a link you're using to access phpinfo (e.g. localhost:63349/index.php)?

Comment: Here's URL / problem. It autocompletes the function but can not run it. https://i.gyazo.com/5b089ea03fd37de40fdd5970e22674f3.png

Comment: Alright, 63342 - is a built-in web server (that doesn't have extensions loaded). A PHP installation that you've edited php.ini for - is it some sort of web-server package like xampp? You should configure/access it by a port you've configured your PHP server for, e.g. localhost:80.

Comment: PHPStorm required me to install PHP. I don't have any PHP servers installed or anything else